# How to organize and rename unicorn_rails process name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, unicorn

I am running a server with multiple Rails apps. I want a different unicorn process name for each app, e.g:

- unicorn_ecommerce for the ecommerce app.
- unicorn_hotsite for the hotsite.

Instead of the traditional "unicorn_rails" for every app. So when I type in the terminal pgrep -lf unicorn I get the apps currently running. I also would like to know if there is a better way to organize your unicorn processes.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while trying to differentiate my unicorn processes in `ps aux | grep unicorn`, not sure if you have the same kind of issues as [Renaming Unicorn processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513119/renaming-unicorn-processes) or if you'd be better served by one of the options in https://askubuntu.com/questions/157075/why-does-ps-aux-grep-x-give-better-results-than-pgrep-x

Just in case someone is looking for better names in `ps aux` there is a pretty simple solution that I'm sure most people figure out by themselves. If you're like me and needed a little help just use the following tip from the manpage:

`Using an absolute path for CONFIG_FILE is recommended as it makes multiple instances of Unicorn easily distinguishable when viewing ps(1) output.`

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/unicorn_rails.1.html (-c, --config-file CONFIG_FILE section)

Answer (score 0):

rename your `/etc/init.d/unicorn_rails` file to anything you want.
then your process will be spawn with this name as well.

Comment: But I think that does not solve the problem. I want different names for different apps. Not just to change the global name.

Comment: This does not change the global name.

Comment: But this will not create a unicorn namespace per app.