# Renaming Unicorn processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, newrelic

I run a Linux server which hosts multiple small Rails apps (for better or worse). The problem is that all apps show up the same in `ps` (see output) and combined in New Relic's server monitoring (see screenshot).

```
$ ps -A
...
25902 ?        00:07:54 ruby
25905 ?        00:07:43 ruby
25914 ?        00:07:59 ruby
25916 ?        00:07:48 ruby
25931 ?        00:08:12 ruby
25935 ?        00:07:04 ruby
28316 ?        00:10:25 ruby
28319 ?        00:09:47 ruby
28548 ?        00:06:01 ruby
28550 ?        00:06:04 ruby
28553 ?        00:05:58 ruby
28561 ?        00:05:55 ruby
28855 ?        00:01:23 ruby
28859 ?        00:01:29 ruby
28896 ?        00:00:12 postgres
28900 ?        00:00:12 postgres
...
```

(I know there are many other options for `ps`'s output, e.g. `ps -auxf`, but they don't really help the New Relic situation)

[image: Snippet of New Relic memory usage]

Ideally, I'd like each app to be identifiable in `ps` and New Relic, e.g.:

```
ruby_some_app (deployer)     480 MB
ruby_another_app (deployer)  260 MB
ruby_that_app (deployer)     512 MB
postgres (postgres)          272 MB
```

Is it possible to rename Unicorn masters and workers such that they don't just show up named "ruby"?

**EDIT**

I've hacked up some Rack middleware which successfully keeps `$0` updated on every request. However, it doesn't make any difference on New Relic.

Comment: this any use?  http://varaneckas.com/blog/unicorn-procline/

Comment: Thanks, seems similar to https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/blob/master/lib/rack/contrib/proctitle.rb. I was really hoping to avoid having to write middleware for this but all signs so far point to Rack.

Comment: You'll be able to tell people you wrote some Rack middleware though, which sounds impressive :0)